# Descartes' trisection of angle - getting the cubic equation

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I am trying to understand Descartes' (original) proof of trisecting an angle. In the first part of the proof he tries to get a cubic equation, but I cannot really follow his argument. Can somebody help me?

[image]

The explanation in the (history of mathematics) book I am reading goes as follows

[image]

I do not understand this argument. I can probably apply anachronistically some trigonometrical identities, but this is not what Descartes was doing.

For those who can read French and want to read the original, see [here](http://debart.pagesperso-orange.fr/geometrie/pages_1637/Geometrie_Descarte_page396.jpg) and [here](http://debart.pagesperso-orange.fr/geometrie/pages_1637/Geometrie_Descarte_page397.jpg).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Triangles $ONQ$ and $NQR$ have angle $\angle NQR$ in common and $\angle NOQ=\angle QNR$, because $\angle NOQ$ is a central angle subtended by an arc which is one half the arc subtending inscribed angle $\angle QNR$. Those triangles are thus similar: from $NO:NQ=NQ:QR$ one gets $QR=NQ^2/NO=z^2$.

Triangles $NQR$ and $QRS$ have angle $\angle NRQ$ in common and $\angle QNR=\angle SQR$ (because $\angle QNR=\angle NOQ=\angle QOT=\angle SQR$). They are thus similar: from $NQ:QR=QR:RS$ one gets $RS=QR^2/NQ=z^3$.

As triangle $NQR$ is isosceles and equal to $TPU$, we also have $NR=NQ=UP=z$. But $QTUS$ is a parallelogram, so that $SU=QT=z$. We have then $NP=NR+UP+SU-SR=3z-z^3$.

Comment: Thank you very much. I almost understanding everything, except the sentence "$\angle NOQ=\angle QNR$, because $\angle NOQ$ is a central angle subtended by an arc which is one half the arc subtending inscribed angle $\angle QNR$."

Comment: An inscribed angle is one half of a central angle subtended by the same arc. In our case $\angle QNP={1\over2}\angle QOP=\angle QON$.